# How to export babel source blocks with syntax highlighting to ODT in org-mode in Emacs 27?

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, odt

In Emacs 27, babel source blocks do not export syntax highlighting to ODT format.

The same org document is exported as expected in Emacs 25.

Versions:

GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.11) of 2017-10-06

Org mode version 9.1.2 (release_9.1.2-40-g6ca906 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.0.50/lisp/org/)

Answer (score 1):

> How to export babel source blocks with syntax highlighting to ODT in org-mode in Emacs 27?

Author of the ODT backend here.

Source syntax highlighting *works* with *the enhanced* ODT backend.

For the impatient, the enhanced ODT backend can be installed by adding  https://kjambunathan.github.io/elpa/ to `package-archives`. You can learn more about the enhanced ODT exporter by visiting the Github repo [The Authoritative fork of Org mode's ODT exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough karma to post a comment, so:

I think that this is a bug in emacs or org mode. I'm submitting a bug report and I'll try to follow it up, hopefully this won't make it into the emacs 26 release.

Here's a link to the intial bug report, I'll try to update this answer in case I learn anything new: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-10/msg00161.html

I have now filed a bug report to emacs to try to get some emacs developers to look at it: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=28806